# STUFF function sql returns null?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a specific column in a table, it shall contains only numbers in `Nvarchar` that have a length of 3. Unfortunately, some users wrote '12' but they should have written '012'. There were not enough validation at the time.

I need to fix that. Here is the logic I used :

```
UPDATE [Mandats_Approvisionnement].[dbo].[ARTICLE_ECOLE] 
SET [UNIT_ADM] = STUFF(UNIT_ADM, 0, 0, '0') 
WHERE LEN(UNIT_ADM) = 2;
```

The error goes like :

> Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'UNIT_ADM', table
>   'Mandats_Approvisionnement.dbo.ARTICLE_ECOLE'; column does not allow
>   nulls. UPDATE fails.

I can't see where the problem is, I verified and all the records contain at least 2 characters, so the `STUFF` function cannot returns null as there are no `NULL` records in that table column `[unit_adm]`... How do I make it work ?

Comment: You could make this simpler by using right('0' + UNIT_ADM, 3) instead of stuff.

Comment: I'm going to try that immediatly

Comment: @Sean Lange if you don't mind, post this as an answer, it worked perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make this simpler by using

```
right('0' + UNIT_ADM, 3)
```

instead of `stuff`.

Comment: And possibly even better: `RIGHT('00' + UNIT_ADM, 3)` in case someone wrote `"7"` into that column .....

Answer (score 6):

It should be `stuff(UNIT_ADM,1,0,'0')` as stuff returns null if the start position is 0.

Citing the documentation:

> If the start position or the length is negative, or if the starting
>   position is larger than length of the first string, a null string is
>   returned. If the start position is 0, a null value is returned.

Comment: I see, the index of that function start at 1, that is also a good answer.